# Duplicate entries in Array

Tags: duplicates

Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return true if there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that nums[i] == nums[j] and abs(i - j) <= k.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1], k = 3
Output: true
```

Example 2:

```
Input: nums = [1,0,1,1], k = 1
Output: true
```

Example 3:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1,2,3], k = 2
Output: false
```

Could anyone tell me why the test case below is true?

```
[1,0,1,1]
1
```

The largest difference should be 2 which is greater than k = 1. Isn't it?

Comment: in `nums = [1,0,1,1]`  for indices `i=2` and `j=3` and `k=1` you have that `nums[i] == nums[j]` and `abs(j-i) <=  k`.  Notice that the question states  `if there are two distinct indices i and j...`  so yes, there exist such indices.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the _largest_ difference - any two indices are acceptable.

Comment: There are two distinct indices (the last two) which are exactly k=1 distance apart and for which the array elements are identical (here, both=1). So ... true

Comment: I don't see how this is a specific programming question, especially when it is tag spammed.

Comment: You forgot to post the code that's (apparently) giving you the wrong result. Please show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Where did you get *largest* from? (The problem statement does not imply "return false if there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that nums[i] == nums[j] and abs(i - j) > k".)

Comment: @CtrlZ: There is no reason to ask for a MRE because this question does not ask why some code is not working. It asks for help understanding a problem statement. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a debugging-assistance site, and you should not assume questions are asking for debugging assistance.

Comment: @ray: Asking how to interpret program specifications is a programming question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right, 2 is larger than 1. However we still have other equal numbers which the difference of their abs value is <= 1. This means you should update the initial index of the value you mapped, initially 1 is mapped with 0 right, but later on it should be updated and mapped to 2. This would mean that abs values (2 - 3) <= 1...

```
for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++)
{
    if(map.containsKey(nums[i]) == true)
    {
        if(Math.abs(map.get(nums[i]) - i) <= k)
        {
            duplicate = true;
        }
        map.put(nums[i], i); // the update i was talking about
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(nums[i], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone tell me why the test case below is true?
>
> ```
> [1,0,1,1]
> 1
> ```
>
> The largest difference should be 2 which is greater than k
> = 1. Isn't it?

The result is `true` given there are two *different* integers `i` and `j` such that they differ at most *k* (here one), such that `nums[i]` and `nums[j]` are the same.

But there are two such indexes, indeed `i = 2` and `j = 3`. These differ and the difference is less than or equal to `1` (exactly one), such that `nums[2] == nums[3]`: both are `1`.